# Ruby hash - create element using an element which is being created within the hash

Tags: ruby, hash

Self descriptive non-working code:

```
mr_hash = {alpha: "hello", bravo: self.alpha + " world"} # Not working...
```

should give

```
{alpha: "hello", bravo: "hello world"}
```

Is it possible, and if so how, to do it within the hash? Without using intermediate variables like:

```
charlie = "hello"
delta = charlie + " world"
mr_hash = {alpha: charlie, bravo: delta}
```

Comment: Why you don't want to use a variable?

Comment: I was hoping to make it more elegant... if you have a long list of hashes, it is desirable to not alternate between defining an intermediate variable and then the only hash which uses it

Comment: Cloth, in future consider holding off awhile before selecting an answer.  A rush to judgment discourages additional answers and (imo) is disrespectful to those still working on theirs.

Comment: @CarySwoveland I agreed with you..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably not what you're looking for but you can use [`Object#tap`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Object.html#method-i-tap) to avoid creating an additional variable:

```ruby
mr_hash = Hash.new.tap do |h|
  h['alpha'] = 'Hello'
  h['bravo'] = h['alpha'] + ' world'
end
mr_hash # => {"alpha"=>"Hello", "bravo"=>"Hello world"}
```

Answer (score 4):

I see @maerics (+1) beat me too it with `tap`.  This is now just a slight variant (I initially included a `merge`, which I removed in light of @Daniël's comment):

```
mr_hash = {alpha: "hello"}.tap {|h| h[bravo] = h[:alpha] + " world"}
```

It still doesn't do what @ClothSword was hoping for, but as @Agis noted, disappointment is inevitable.

Comment: No need for your merge though? `mr_hash = {alpha: "hello"}.tap {|h| h[:bravo] = h[:alpha] + " world"}` is equivalent.

Comment: I'd be greatful for an explanation for the downvote, but I've been at SO long enough to know that I probably won't get it.

Comment: @CarySwoveland: not the downvoter but, ya, I wish a downvote required a comment.

Answer (score 3):

*No*, it is not possible, because the line of code must be interpreted first so the hash is created.

Comment: This is--can be--the only correct answer, for the reason given. +1